# Schematic Confusion: How to connect the Ground Terminal?

Tags: pcb, schematics, circuit-design

[image]

GND means ground. How am I supposed to connect this GND ? Does it means that I have to simply hook up a wire and leave it floating? What is it's significance in the circuit?
I am designing a PCB and I want to know how to connect this GND in a PCB???

Comment: It's been a while since I used Eagle but I don't think your LEDs are connected to 3.3V.

Answer (score 2):

GND in an electric circuit is nothing more then a reference. This is the position from were all potentials are given unless specifically indicated otherwise.

In this case GND has nothing to do with Earth or mains GND.
If you have a powersupply then in your case the negative line of the DC goes to GND. and the positive line goes to VCC.

Answer (score 0):

You connect it to the net called "GND". If there's nothing else in the schematic that connects to the GND net then nothing connects to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an instruction that you measure any voltages in the schematic with respect to this node.

If you are building a board to this schematic, this is the node that connects to the plane that floods the PCB, and connects to the case if it's metallic.

Most simulators will require one node to be labelled 'gnd', so they have a reference to measure and display the nodal voltages against.